# pyodbc.connect - works from one computer but not another

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have been running Python script using my desktop at work that successfully connects to a remote desktop server and outputs data in SQL via pyodbc.connect.

I am looking to migrate this code to a separate remote desktop PC recently installed at work and I get the following error:

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The code I am using is:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                  "Server=AUBAMTRAS01-DEV;"
                  "Database=ForwardTrading;"
                  "Username=xxxxxxxx;"
                  "Password=yyyyyyyy;"
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT distinct(Commodity) from ForwardCurvesOilAndGas')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Comment: Which PC operating system are you using? You'll likely need to go into the 'odbcini' settings on whatever machine you're using and configure your PC to see the driver after you install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED - Driver required was 'SQL Server' not 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'

Answer (score 0):

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

This means you need to install the SQLDriverConnect driver on your second machine.